CMake error when trying to install latte-dock from github repo
I am using Arch with Kde plasma.
I was trying to install latte-dock and in some videos it showed that you could do that by simply using pacman -S latte-dock, but now the package cant be found anymore, now i tried using their github repo, but when i execute the install.sh i get this:
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:1 (project):
  cmake_minimum_required() should be called prior to this top-level project()
  call.  Please see the cmake-commands(7) manual for usage documentation of
  both commands.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error: Could not open file for write in copy operation /home/matter/Customization/latte-dock/build/prefix.sh.tmp
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
CMake Error at /usr/share/ECM/kde-modules/KDESetupPrefixScript.cmake:18 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/ECM/kde-modules/KDEInstallDirs5.cmake:386 (include)
  /usr/share/ECM/kde-modules/KDEInstallDirs.cmake:15 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:22 (include)


CMake Error: Could not open file for write in copy operation /home/matter/Customization/latte-dock/build/ecm_uninstall.cmake.tmp
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
CMake Error at /usr/share/ECM/modules/ECMUninstallTarget.cmake:39 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/ECM/kde-modules/KDECMakeSettings.cmake:284 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (include)


CMake Error at /usr/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Qml" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5QmlConfig.cmake
    qt5qml-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Qml" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Qml_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5Qml"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:33 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake Error: Cannot open file for write: /home/matter/Customization/latte-dock/build/CMakeCache.txt.tmpa1a3c
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
CMake Error: Unable to open cache file for save. /home/matter/Customization/latte-dock/build/CMakeCache.txt
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied


I tried to install qt5-dev, like they say in the github repo instructions, but again this package doesnt exists and i am still dealing with this error.
